# passing a value is undefined in function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-table

I´m trying to pass a value inside of my function but the result is undefined

```
function ExpanseTable() {

const [month, setMonth] = useState('Dec')
console.log(month + "     outside function") // Dec



const updateMyData = (rowIndex, columnId, value, id, testValue ) => {
  console.log(month + "     inside function") //undefined
  };
}
```

updateMyData is called in

```
 <Table
    updateMyData={updateMyData}
  />
```

Comment: *I´m trying to pass a value* - how exactly? You haven't showed us where the function is actually called, just that it's passed to `Table`. What is `Table`? Is that custom? A library? *That* is where you would *pass* values to the function.

Comment: Thank you very much! Passed it into my Table Function and it works.